# Download table generated independently in renderTable output in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to generate a table using the renderTable function in R shiny and then use the downloadHandler function to download that table/data.frame as a csv file. Somehow I keep getting the following error:

> An error occured during download: 
>   Error downloading http://127:0:0.1:3001/session/
>   0303bd426fce88837ae277aa3b406dd/download/downloadData?w= - server 
>   replied: Internal Server Error

Below is an example code where I generate a simple data frame and try to download it using downloadHander:

```
library(shiny)
 # Define UI for data download app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Downloading Data"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            # Button
            downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

        ),

        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(

            tableOutput("table")

        )

    )
)
# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    # Table of selected dataset ----
    output$table <- renderTable({
        data.frame(a =c(1,2,3),b=c("q","s","f"))
    })

    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste("test.csv")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            write.csv(output$table, file, row.names = FALSE)
        }
    )

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: `renderTable()` prepares the output for the UI. I think what you want is to create  a `reactive()` data frame that can be called by `renderTable` and `downloadHandler`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that need to be done here:

1. If your app is going to render data dynamically, then your data should be assigned to some `reactive` expression.
2. Now the downloading of the data becomes easy, as you just call the `reactive` expression written in (1).

   - Points (1) and (2) above will ensure that the user is downloading the same data that is seen on the screen.

Try the following:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- shiny::reactive(data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("q", "s", "f")))
  output$table <- renderTable(data())

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("test.csv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot export a renderTable{} as this puts many of the elements into HTML, 
 you need to previously save the data going into the table and export it 
 seperately.

```
dataTable<-data.frame(a =c(1,2,3),b=c("q","s","f"))

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {
    ('test.csv')
  }, 

  content = function(con) {
    write.table(dataTable,row.names = FALSE,col.names=T, sep=",",con)
  },
  contentType="csv"
)
```

Comment: Good answer, though you really should make `dataTable` a `reactive` if you want this to be usable in an actual shiny app

Comment: I think that depends on the nature of his/her app, as you could observe a button to create the data frame, create a reactive function, or as you said create a data set reactive to user inputs. Either way I do not have that information and setting up the data table is simply an example. @divibisan